# looping through and deleting header in specific directories

Tags: linux, sed

I want to loop through only specific directories and delete the first line of files given as input parameters in those directories.

My input parameters should be:

- `-i [input_directory]` - root directory
- `-n [directory]` directories to check for files
- `file ending`

Run as

```
sh -i /main/folder/ -n (sub1|sub2|sub6) .txt
```

Script should only delete header for `*.txt` files in `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub6` folders under `/main/folder/`.

Now I have below script which loops through all folders and deletes header but I am not sure how to loop through only specified folder

```
for $file in $i/*/*.txt do
    sed '1,1d' $file
done
```

Please let me know if there will be any use if we change the way we input parameters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework.

Comment: I am not asking to write the script but just wanted to know the approach. Only idea I got is loop through all directories by splitting based on the delimitter . I just wanted to know if we have any better approches

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro He showed what he worked out so far and asks for specific help. Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: You can look for files in `sub1`, and then look for files in `sub2`, and then look for files in `sub6`.  In other words, you could loop over the subdirectories (``sub1``, ``sub2``, and `sub6`).  Or you could do a single loop over all the files, and, for each one, check whether it is in one of the subdirectories you are interested in.  If there might be 1003 subdirectories (i.e., 1000 that you want to ignore), you should probably use the first approach.  But either could work.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition about commands that let you specify a working directory is, that it is the first parameter. That you have correct, although you could lose the `-i` command switch.

Secondly any options with multiple values (like the multiple specific sub-directories you want to search in) should be last. That way they don't interfere too much with the other ones.

I would propose to call your command like this:

```
~$ mycommand /my/root/dir "txt" -sdirs sub1 sub2 sub6
```

Bash and maybe `sh` as well has the `shift` builtin, which lets you shift through the given arguments. You could extract the necessary information from the commandline like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

WORK_DIR="$1"
shift # shifts $2 to $1
FILE_END="$1"
shift
if [ "-sdirs" = "$1" ]; then
    shift # get to the sub dirs
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do # tests if there is a sub dir
        # *do your magic here*
        # $1 should be a sub dir
        # $WORK_DIR/$1/*$FILE_END for example

        # to the next one, break if nothing left
        shift || break
    done
else
    echo "No sub directories specified"
    exit 1
fi
```

This is what I would do off the top of my head. More error handling is appropriate and left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: +1 for “left as an exercise to the reader.”  But seriously, why are you checking for ```-n``` on the command line?

Comment: @G-Man Good catch. I forgot that I changed the option name.